# How to programmatically customize a polygonal frame view on iOS?

Tags: ios, frame, polygon

Is there any possible to customize a view which it's frame is a polygon(such as a triangle) instead of a regular rectangle? (not just "draw" a polygon shape with CG)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, all views in iOS have a rectangular frame.